# tryCatch to Prevent R Shiny App Crushing on MySQL Connection Error

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, connection

My Shiny App was crushing when wrong connection credentials were passed to the connection string.  I then put my connection string within a tryCatch as follows:
,,,

```
 ConnectToDb <- function(){
        con <- tryCatch({
          dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                    user = input$db_user,
                    password = input$db_password,
                    dbname = input$db_name,
                    host = input$db_host,
                    port = input$db_port)
          print("Connection made")
          ####
          sql <- "SELECT * FROM PMSAnalytics;"
          
          data <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
          
          #   # Disconnect from the DB
          dbDisconnect(con)
          #   # Convert to data.frame
          data <- data.frame(data)
          data$timestamp <- as_datetime(now())
          data
          ####
          
        }, error = function(e) {
          message('Please confirm your login details')
          print(e)
        },
        warning = function(w){
          message('A warning has occured')
          print(w)
          return(NA)
        }
        )
      }
```

,,,
Now the application does not crush, but however no error messages or warning are passed when wrong credentials are used and neither do I get a connection success.  I have checked this site for similar questions, but I seem not to get any.  Kindly assist with polishing the code.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I work with `showNotification`, which directly shows a notification in the shiny UI, you could also use it for the connection success.
Also, Options for this are,

- duration = 60 (in this case for 60 seconds)
- closeButton = FALSE

For example:

```
error = function(e) {
    showNotification(paste0(e), type = 'error')

}

warning = function(w){
    showNotification(paste0(w), type = 'warning')
    return(NA)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mustafa for your input.  I will try it out and update you.